# Javascript name array input selectors (name[sometext])

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

How can I select a named input like this properly in jQuery without assigning ID's?

```
<input name="person[first]" type="hidden">
<input name="person[last]" type="hidden">

// Seems to be acting on multiple hidden elements instead of this named one
// This sets the value of both of those hidden elements in some cases
$("input[type=hidden][name=person[first]]").val('Test');

// So I've changed it to this. Is there a better way?
$("input[name=person[first]]").val('Test');
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what's not working when you have multiple hidden input elements with the HTML included? It's not clear from your example.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Put the attribute value in quotes...

```
$("input[type=hidden][name='person[first]']").val();
   // ---------------------^-------------^
```

---

*From [the docs for attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)...*

> **attribute** An attribute name.
>
> **value** An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string.

Since you have more than just a single word, it should be quoted.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you're supposed to put in quotes any attribute selector's value that includes symbols with meaning in CSS. Like this:

```
input[type=hidden][name='person[first]']
```